# Access var from function (Struct)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a "`struct`" and use it the same way I would in any other programming language (namely Swift). Here's the "struct":

```
var myStruct = function (prop1) {
    this.prop1 = 30;
}
```

I then access `prop1` like this:

```
var someVar = myStruct.prop1
```

For some reason that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix this?

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3dfpkrp0/), and here's the full code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myStruct = function (prop1) {
  this.prop1 = 30;
 }
    
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").css({"width": myStruct.prop1, "font-size": "200%"});
    });
});
```

```html
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Set multiple styles for p</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've made is an [Object Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor), to get an object from the constructor you would use the `new` keyword to create a new instance of the object. However, you shouldn't use this unless you need to create multiple instances of the object.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myStruct = function () {
        this.prop1 = 30;
    }

    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").css({"width": new myStruct().prop1, "font-size": "200%"});
    });
});
```

If you don't need to have separate instances of the object, you can create a new Object using the syntax demonstrated in the example below.

Notes:

- This syntax allows you to access the properties in the manner you attempted in your example.
- You are already passing an object using this syntax to the `$('p').css()` method in the example below.
- Properties declared using this syntax should be separated using commas instead of semicolons, this is the same as when using the array syntax.
- Any object property whose name contains special characters must be enclosed in quotation marks and can only be accessed using the `object["property"]` notation.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myStruct = {
        width: '30px',
        fontsize: '200%'
    }
    
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").css({
            "width": myStruct.width, 
            "font-size": myStruct.fontsize
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>This is a heading</h2>

<p style="background-color:#ff0000">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#00ff00">This is a paragraph.</p>
<p style="background-color:#0000ff">This is a paragraph.</p>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<button>Set multiple styles for p</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

To use a **constructor** to create the **objects**, use:

```
function MyClass(prop) {
    this.prop = prop;
}
```

To create an **object** of that type, use:

```
var obj = new MyClass(30);
```

To reference the **property** of the **object**, use:

```
console.log(obj.prop);
```

Since **30** was passed in to the object, this.prop is set to **30** and that value will be displayed in the log.

Thanks to @Tiny_Giant for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

This is the class declaration:

```
var myStruct = function (prop1) {
    this.prop1 = 30;
}
```

This is the class implementation:

```
var obj = new myStruct(1);
```